# How To Correctly Use Patch Request (Mongoose & Express)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, httprequest

I have a patch request that updates the status of the order. I have organized the statuses in an array in a MongoDB database. This code is working properly but I am wondering if this way of updating is correct. Should I use any operators like `$set`? *I am using Mongoose and Express and NodeJS btw.*

Here is the code:

```
module.exports.updateStatus = async (req, res) => {
    const { orderid } = req.params;
    const { heading } = req.body;

    const order = await Order.findById(orderid);
    for (let i = 0; i < order.status.length; i++) {
        if (order.status[i].heading === 'Arrived At Location') {
            req.flash('error', 'Order is already marked as fulfilled.');
            return res.redirect(`/orders/${orderid}`);
        }
    }
    order.status.push({ heading, date: new Date() });
    await order.save();
    res.redirect(`/orders/${orderid}`);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you manage to find an answer for this? I am into the same. Thank you

Comment: @JavierGuzmán Yeah I read that updating using the method above stores data in memory. Instead you should use methods such as Collection.findByIdAndUpdate(). But it doesn’t work for all situations thus requiring you to query for a document multiple times. So I’m sticking to my original method.